# Binomial approximation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

A fair die is rolled 800 times. Find the probability to get a 6 at least 150 times.

My attempt:

The probability to get exactly 150 6's is:

$\binom{800}{150}\left(\frac16\right)^{150}\left(\frac56\right)^{800-150}$

The required probability is the **sum** of getting 150, 151 etc.

I understand we must use some approximation here, because we can't do these calculations one by one.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you studying the normal approximation to the binomial distribution?  Because that's probably what I'd employ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statistical survey of two genders in two cities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133985/statistical-survey-of-two-genders-in-two-cities)

Comment: @Stacker what's the relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One *can* use a normal approximation to normal to find the probability that
For $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 800, p = 1/6),$ one *can* use a normal approximation to find $P(X \ge 150) = 1 - P(X\le 149) = 0.06420055,$ correct
to 2 (maybe 3) places. Or one can use software to get a more precise value. Computation in R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF:

```
1 - pbinom(149, 800, 1/6)
[1] 0.06420055
```

In R, the normal approximation gives the $P(X \ge 150) \approx 0.06255,$ as shown
below:

```
n = 800;  p = 1/6;
mu = n*p;  sg = sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
mu;  sg
[1] 133.3333
[1] 10.54093
1 - pnorm(149.5, mu, sg)
[1] 0.06255116
```

You can also standardize to get a normal approximation in terms of a
standard normal random variable $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}.$ I will leave
the details of using a printed standard normal table to you. You will not
get *exactly* the value below because some rounding is involved in using
printed tables. [The use of 149.5 is called the continuity correction, which often gives a slightly closer approximation.]

```
1 - pnorm((149.5-mu)/sg)
[1] 0.06255116
```

In the figure below, the desired probability is the sum of the heights of the
blue bars to the right of the vertical dotted line and the approximate
probability is the area under the orange curve to the right of that line.

[image]

```
x = 100:180;  PDF = dbinom(x, 800, 1/6)
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(800, 1/6) with Density of NORM(133.33, 10.54)"
plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 149.5, lty = "dotted", lwd=2)
```

Comment: Totally forgot about pbinom lol!

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with distributions: $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$. So $Z = \frac{800 -133.33}{10.54}$? And where does 149.5 come from?

Comment: Continuity correction for normal approx. Area under normal curve corresponding to binomial X = 150 is above interval $(149.5, 150.5)$ under density curve. See figure. // If it's not in your text, then many you're not intended to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Let Xi be Bernoulli with p=1/6. The CLT says that X, the sum of number of rolls of a 6, is approximately normal with mean 800/6 and variance 800/6(5/6). The needed probability is Pr(X>=150). Standardize and compute the probability. Pr(Z>(150-mu)/stddev). With continuity correction, Pr(X>=149.5). The continuity correction should give a closer estimate to the truth.